# Table Value Constructor with identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server how can I add a ordinal/identity/row number to this result set?

```
select * 
from (VALUES('c'), ('a'), ('b')) t(value)
```

| value |
| --- |
| c |
| a |
| b |

So it returns the same as this:

```
select * 
from STRING_SPLIT('c,a,b', ',', 1) t
```

| value | ordinal |
| --- | --- |
| c | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 3 |

I don't want to just do `VALUES(1,'c'),(2,'a'),(3,'b')` because there will be a long list that will change from time to time and can't have gaps in the ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using the `values` constructor, the closest you can get is to use a table variable with an identity column e.g.

```
declare @Test table ([Value] varchar(32), Ordinal int identity (1,1));

insert into @Test ([Value])
values ('c'),('a'),('b');

select *
from @Test
order by Ordinal;
```

Returns

| Value | Ordinal |
| --- | --- |
| c | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 3 |

Comment: I meant in-line sorry

Comment: @user433342 you can't - this is the next best thing.

Comment: Eh might as well use split thx